# How to update multiple ids in wordpress php and mysql(I am trying to update quetion and answer in quiz app)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update

I am tryting update answers with different quetion ids but only one first id will be updated so how to fix , please help...thank you in advance

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$updated_id'" ;
    $user = $wpdb->get_var($sql);  
           
    if ($user){       
        if (isset($_POST['question_id'])) {           
        $updated = $wpdb->update( $table, ['quetion' =>$quetion], ['id' => $updated_id ] );         
        global $wpdb;
        $update_quetionids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT id FROM wp_quetion_answer WHERE quetion_id = $updated_id");
        print_r($update_quetionids);    
     foreach($update_quetionids as $key => $value1){
      foreach($answers as $key=>$value){
         if($correct_answer == $value){
               $is_correct = 1;
            }
         else{
            $is_correct = 0;
            }
            
       $data = array('is_correct' => $is_correct,
      'answers'=>$value,   
       );  
    }
       print_r($data);
     $where = array('id' => $value1);}
     $wpdb->update(
        'wp_quetion_answer',
         $data,
         $where,
        );
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with all that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that the queries you've posted are vulnerable for SQL injection - please have a  look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: I am trying to update multiple rows ids  in wordpress and next time i used prepare query pl

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: plz ..help ? it would be appreciated..

Comment: I make quiz app in this one quetion has multiple answers , i try to update quetion and answers how to fix it... in my code (in this) only first answer is updated ...

Comment: Have you any solution ....?